# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop and post to API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array that is made of multiple objects (9 to be exact). I'm looping through the array using .map() and then use axios.post() to post each single object with its corresponding name to a MySQL database.

However, when I run the code it gives me the error message:
"Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop" which is being caused by the "parsedData.map()" function.

How can I avoid that, so that I can get each objects data and send it to the API?

```
    const [parsedData, setParsedData] = useState([]);
    const [addInputData, SetAddInputData] = useState([]);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        Papa.parse(event.target.files[0], {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: function (results) {
                setParsedData(results.data);
            },
        });
    };

    parsedData.map((person) => {
        SetAddInputData({
            status: person.status,
            first_name: person.first_name,
            last_name: person.last_name,
            position: person.position,
            email: person.email,
            phone: person.phone,
            image_url: person.image_url,
            linked_in: person.linked_in,
            business_name: person.business_name,
            postcode: person.postcode,
            icebreaker: person.icebreaker,
            paragraph_one: person.paragraph_one,
            paragraph_two: person.paragraph_two,
            paragraph_three: person.paragraph_three,
            call_to_action: person.call_to_action,
        });
        addNewLead({ addInputData }); // axios.post(`${base_url}/leads`, addInputData) in a different file
    });
```

Comment: What is `addNewLead` ?

Comment: Uhm, maybe you should move your `parsedData.map` stuff inside an `useEffect` with `parsedData` as dependency?

Comment: It's the function in which the axios .post() request is stored (in a different file). I then just imported the addNewLead function and call it inside the page above to trigger the axios .post() request.

Comment: Don't place state update inside a React mount, state updates should only happen inside `useEffect` or some form of event, like click etc, otherwise your just constantly doing a state update, aka infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, a component re-renders whenever one of these 2 cases occurs:

1. Whenever there is a change in the component's local state.
2. Whenever any of it's parent components themselves are re-rendered.

Now, whenever a component re-renders, it re-evaluates all logic within it as well.
Meaning that if you were to put a `map` function inside of the component like in your example, it will `map` every time the component re-renders.

And since you set the component's state within that `map` function, it creates a loop that looks like this:

- The component mounts
- The `map` function is being called
- The `map` function sets the state
- The component re-renders
- The `map` function runs again

And so on, and so forth...
This creates what is called an "infinite loop", and it ultimately results in the error you are receiving, which is an error caught by React in-order to avoid the usual case with infinite loops, in-which the browser would freeze and eventually crash.

As for the solution, the way we usually handle state population with the value returned from `async` calls, is via the `useEffect` hook, which is a built-in React hook that activates a callback whenever there is a change in any of it's dependencies.

Also, you probably don't want to set the state within the `map` function.
It will reset the state with an object with every iteration instead of setting it as an array of those object.
You likely want to wrap the `map` function with the `setState` function.

**Example:**

```
function MyComp() {
   const [parsedData, setParsedData] = useState([]);
   const [addInputData, setAddInputData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      setAddInputData(parsedData.map(person => ({
         status: person.status,
         first_name: person.first_name,
         last_name: person.last_name,
         position: person.position,
         email: person.email,
         phone: person.phone,
         image_url: person.image_url,
         linked_in: person.linked_in,
         business_name: person.business_name,
         postcode: person.postcode,
         icebreaker: person.icebreaker,
         paragraph_one: person.paragraph_one,
         paragraph_two: person.paragraph_two,
         paragraph_three: person.paragraph_three,
         call_to_action: person.call_to_action,
      })));
   }, []); // A useEffect with an empty dependency array should run only once when the component first mounts.

   useEffect(() => {
      addNewLead({ addInputData });
   }, [addInputData]); // A useEffect that is dependent upon a state, will run every time that state was set.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is inside of a functional component you are in fact causing an infinite loop. Each time the component function runs `parsedData.map(...)` runs and updates the `addInputData` state causing another run of the component function, and another call to `parsedData.map(...)`

The `addInputData` is *derived* state from `parsedData`, so you should probably do your update stuff in a `useEffect(...,[parsedData])`. Another option would be to use the primary state directly and not do the derived state at all. Although without `useEffect` you are going to call the axios api every time the component renders.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. I initially didn't use the useEffect because I was worried that it would then only run once and not spit out all objects, but rather than just one. Well, looks like I was wrong. I've just added the useEffect and now it's almost working as I wanted to. Thanks!

Comment: @timohuennebeck Everything in the map will finish. The useEffect will run once every time parsedData changes, and once the first time the component mounts! To handle they case you might check if parsedData is actually set (not an empty array) before doing the update stuff.